# Normed Scalar Error/Objective Function vs Vectorial Error/Objective Function in Newton Raphson

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I am working on an harmonic balance solver which involves finding the zeros of the objective/error function using the Newton Raphson method. Presently I am using a vectorial error function but I have seen many implementations where a scalar error function is used by employing a norm. I was wondering if a scalar normed error function could offer any advantages concerning stability of the algorithm as opposed to a vectorial error function since I am currently facing issues with convergence to an alternative solution(unwanted root).